# Multiple CSS classes to style a Button w/ Rails and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails 3.1 and Twitter Bootstrap, but struggling to replicate `<a class="btn btn-large" href="">Button!</a>` with a rails helper.

With the CSS giving providing the 'button', I'm not sure whether I should be using `link_to` or `button_to`, but I DO know that neither of them are giving me the appropriately styled button.

I've tried a variety of combinations, for instance:

`<%= button_to "Button!", :class => "btn btn-large" %>`

How can I replicate my normal HTML link with a rails helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `link_to` :

```
<%= link_to 'Button!', '#', :class => 'btn btn-large' %>
```

I use it in this way and it works perfectly.

The `button_to` helper generate a form with a button. Here, you just want a link with a button appearance.

Comment: Note: if JavaScript is disabled, this solution does not work for other methods than GET.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify multiple classse for a HTML element as `<element class="foo bar">`, not as `<element class="foo" class="bar">`. This might seem slightly counter-intuitive, I agree.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but it's the Rails helper version of this that I can't get working. :)  I'll edit the question to reflect the proper HTML syntax.